# Webpack: How NOT to merge files into a bundle after Babel transpilation?

Tags: javascript, webpack, compilation, ecmascript-6, babeljs

### Is there a setting in Webpack that allows to save files (after Babel compilation from es6/7 to es5) preserving the original file structure ?

Webpack is powerful instrument for frontend development.
But as I can see it always create single bundle (or couple of chunks).

---

For example, I have file structure like:

```
src
  index.js (es6/7)
  components
    App.js (es6/7)
    Widget.js (es6/7)
```

After compilation Webpack create:

```
bundles
  bundle.js (es5)
```

or chunks:

```
bundles
  chunk1.js (es5)
  chunk2.js (es5)
```

But I need to get my **file structure untouched** (**and create bundle** with same code as a plus) **after Babel compilation**:

```
lib
  index.js (es5)
  components
    App.js (es5)
    Widget.js (es5)
bundles
  bundle.js (es5)
```

---

**Why it can be useful ?**

1. For run code on Node.js server. Server don't need single bundle and require files asynchronously.
2. Optimizing the compilation speed. If file App.js was compiled in es5 and don't have changed, Webpack don't need to do this again. Just add  code from file (lib/*/App.js with es5) to bundle.
3. Easier debug.

Comment: I know that gulp + browserify can solve my task. But Webpack advertises himself as better and universal tool. As for me, this is a common task in isomorphic development on JavaScript.
So I interested, can Webpack resolve this ?

Comment: The entire goal of Webpack is to bundle things into a single file. If you don't want that, then you shouldn't be using Webpack.